# vercel.json having problems with public files

Tags: javascript, express, server, vercel

I'm making [this project](https://github.com/eduairet/collectible-pleasures/tree/master/server) and I'm having trouble with the Vercel server, this is the error I'm getting:

```
Refused to execute https://collectible-pleasures-server.vercel.app/sketch.js as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

I've tried several configurations in `vercel.json` but nothings working, Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to change `vercel.json` this is what I got so far:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "public/**",
            "use": "@vercel/static"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "index.js"
        },
        {
            "src": "/?nft=*",
            "dest": "public/sketch.html"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.+)",
            "dest": "public/$1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Solved the issue by removing te express static function and retrieving each file with 200 status, also by adding * cross origin, check vercel.json   https://github.com/eduairet/collectible-pleasures/blob/master/server/vercel.json the CORS config https://github.com/eduairet/collectible-pleasures/blob/master/server/index.js and the way I sent the files https://github.com/eduairet/collectible-pleasures/blob/master/server/controllers/sketch-controller.js